# Why Google Calendar API returns timeZone=UTC although it's incorrect?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Most of our customers are American, but after connecting their google calendar with our service we read timeZone=UTC:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?minAccessRole=owner&access_token=<ACCSES TOKEN>
```

response:

```
{
"kind": "calendar#calendarList",
"etag": "\"1407366566837000\"",
"nextSyncToken": "00001407366566837000",
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry",
        "etag": "\"1407184723757000\"",
        "id": "sampleemail@gmail.com",
        "summary": "sampleemail@gmail.com",
        "timeZone": "UTC",
        "colorId": "17",
        "backgroundColor": "#9a9cff",
        "foregroundColor": "#000000",
        "selected": true,
        "accessRole": "owner",
        "defaultReminders": [
            {
                "method": "popup",
                "minutes": 30
            }
        ],
        "notificationSettings": {
            "notifications": [
                {
                    "type": "eventCreation",
                    "method": "email"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eventChange",
                    "method": "email"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eventCancellation",
                    "method": "email"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eventResponse",
                    "method": "email"
                }
            ]
        },
        "primary": true
    }
]
```

}

it happens to a lot of users, and we're pretty sure their calendar is actually not set to UTC, but Google consistently returns UTC.
Anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that their calendars are not in UTC? Perhaps they have never logged in to Google Calendar and therefore never setup a timezone.

Comment: yes. i actually got utc on my own calendar connection although it's not utc. regarding most of our users i cant know for sure. is tgrre a different way to know?

Comment: The value returned by the API should correspond to the value found next to "Calendar Time Zone:" in the Calendar Settings screen (pull down next to calendar > Calendar settings).

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/2367918?hl=en

> How Calender Treats time zones
>
> Whenever you create an event, Calendar converts it from your time zone
>   to UTC time, using currently known conversion rules. By using one
>   universal time for all events, Calendar can keep all of your guests’
>   calendars consistent regardless of which time zones they're in. When
>   we display the event on your calendar, it is converted from UTC to
>   appear in your own time zone.

My backend ruby code:

```
time_zone = 'Europe/Moscow'
task_time_start_utc = task.date_time
task_time_start_moscow = task_time_start_utc.in_time_zone(time_zone)

task_time_end_utc = task_time_start_utc + task.duration.minutes
task_time_end_moscow = task_time_end_utc.in_time_zone(time_zone)

event_property = {
    summary: task.name,
    location: "#{task.lat} #{task.lng}",
    description: string_work_times,
    start: {
        date_time: task_time_start_moscow.to_formatted_s(:iso8601),
        time_zone: time_zone
    },
    end: {
        date_time: task_time_end_moscow.to_formatted_s(:iso8601),
        time_zone: time_zone
    }
}
```